# Why doesn't the nugget for a covariance matrix for a Gaussian Process appear in the whole diagonal

Tags: statistics, covariance, gaussian-process

In the covariance matrix of a GP with noise, one adds a nugget to the top-left covariance block, which is the covariance for the observed responses. But what about the bottom-right block- the one with the target observations? The nugget is omitted for this block. You can find what I mean on page 16 of https://gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf What is the reason for this? Thanks!